# Making bookshelf.js work with existing data

Tags: node.js, postgresql, bookshelf.js, knex.js

My team has just started using bookshelf.js in our node app with knex. By default, the ORM object uses an id field which is created as a "serial" type in postgresql. We have existing data that we need to insert into the DB. My understanding is that the database "id" field will want to start with 1.

- So is there a way to have a postgres serial number start at a particular number (also will there be issues with using a clustered database and the serial datatype)?
- Is there a way to set the field to an "integer" field type through knex/bookshelf and use a sequence to nextval?
- Any other options (not looking for extreme hacks here either)?

We are using the following stack:

- Postgres: 9.x
- NodeJs: 4.4.4 LTS
- Knex: 0.11.8
- Bookshelf: 0.10.0

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Nick, my experience i manly with knex, however if the docs are right you have a quite good freedom about hot the table itself behaves: http://bookshelfjs.org/#associations For instance you can make a model to solve associations but can use knex schema builder to manage/migrate the database: http://knexjs.org/#Chainable-primary Also, if everything else fails, you can use knex.raw to gain access to the postgres and fine-craft the sequenses the way you need them: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-createsequence.html#AEN43529